# For Next VBA skips half

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a simple VBA in Excel, to copy some data I am trying to regroup. I seems to work good for some part, but it skips a row and column everytime! The problem must be somewhere in the double For..Next.. I am using, but I can't find it:

The result I get:

[image: result]

```
For i = 1 To AantalPag 'HIERRR
    GezSite = BeginCel.Offset(i + 1) 'HIERRR
    For iweek = 1 To AantalWeek
        GezWeek = BeginCel.Offset(0, iweek)
            For i2 = 1 To AantalWeekData
                If BeginCelData.Offset(i2 - 1) = GezWeek Then
                    For i3 = 1 To AantalSitesData
                        If BeginCelData.Offset(0, i3) = GezSite Then
                           Sommetje = Sommetje + BeginCelData.Offset(i2 - 1, i3 - 1)                            
                        Else
                           i3 = i3 + 1
                        End If
                    Next i3
                    'BeginCel.Offset(i, iweek) = Sommetje
                    'Sommetje = 0
                Else
                    i2 = i2 + 1
                End If
            Next i2
            BeginCel.Offset(i, iweek) = Sommetje
            Sommetje = 0
        iweek = iweek + 1
    Next iweek
    i = i + 1
Next i
```

Comment: What result were you hoping to see and what did the data look like to start with? Showing the actual result without this lacks context.

Comment: Could that be caused by lines `i=i+1`, `i2=i2+1` and `i3=i3+1`? In a `for` loop the variable is already incremented automatically, so only in special cases should you increment it yourself.

Comment: Such deeply nested code is too convoluted and is a sign that you might need to rethink your algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will print the numbers from 1 to 100 in the Immediate window.

```
For n = 1 to 100
    Debug.Print n
Next n
```

The code below will print every other number in the Immediate window. This is because `n` is incremented both by `n = n + 1` and then again by `Next n`.

```
For n = 1 to 100
    Debug.Print n
    n = n + 1
Next n
```

Comment: thanks for all the help! Clearly I am a beginner ;)

I adding the +1 was incorrect indeed, I did this trying to solve another problem, which seems to be caused by the maximum characters a integer can use, my data was a lot bigger. Changed that for double

Comment: @JeroenAnimalRescuer You are right about the limitations of `Integer`, but `Long` is a better alternative than `Double` since `Long` is still an integer type.

Comment: all row and column numbers are "naturally" of `Long` data type, meaning that is the type Excel processes internally. If you specify another type, such as `Integer`, `Single` or `Double` Excel will have to convert that to `Long` for processing..